# Remove a "scheduled add" from SVN repo

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

This may be a newbie questions but I have been working with Subversion (SVN) for a while now and today something odd happen. I use Tortoise SVN for windows to manage my local working copies. I was in the middle of updating all of my working copies and I noticed that there were 2 branch folders that were duplicates. I right clicked the duplicate folder to delete it but on accident I clicked "ADD+". I realized the mistake and to correct it I simply deleted the duplicate folder from the hard drive. However now when I try to commit the main folder I am getting the following error .

> Commit Commit failed (details follow):
>   'C:_SVN\site\branches\newui\images' is scheduled for addition, but 
>   is missing

This error is correct that folder is "missing" I deleted it. However now tortoise wont let me commit the folder so my working copy is out of sync.

My question is, is there a way to "reset" or "clear" scheduled additions from the repo? How can I get past this issue?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some possibilities to fix this:

- call revert on the folder: Tortoise SVN will offer you to recreate the missing folder
- call undo Add on the folder: Tsvn should realize, that there is an add in the folder and the add should be reverted.
- Possibly a cleanup call is required to fix things before trying and after trying one of the methods above.

If nothing helps, zip or rename the folders in question to be sure they are safe and then checkout a new copy and then replace the contents with your folders. That can be committed and then you can safely delete the folder.

One tip: I usually delete folders in the repo-browser and then call an update on the folder in the working directory. This usually works better.

Comment: Thank you :) The "Revert" worked. I didn't think to try that. Going forward I will just use the SVN browser too, seems safer that way.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, do only that I did:

1. Right-click - svn commit...
2. after svn explore you can easily see your missing files or deleted file.
3. just right click on that end delete it.
4. close the current window.

Next time you will commit your file no error will show

That's it.